# Python Convert Counters into DataFrame Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, counter

I haven't been able to find an answer here specific to my issue and I'm wondering if I could get some help (apologies for the links, I'm not allowed to embed images yet).

I have stored Counter objects within my DataFrame and also want them added to the DataFrame as a column for each counted element.

Beginning data

```
data = {
    "words": ["ABC", "BCDB", "CDE", "F"],
    "stuff": ["abc", "bcda", "cde", "f"]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[Preliminary Data Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzm3M.png)

```
patternData = {
    "name": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"],
    "rex": ["A{1}", "B{1}", "C{1}", "D{1}", "E{1}", "F{1}"]
}
patterns = pd.DataFrame(patternData)
```

[Pattern DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrvVN.png)

```
def countFound(ps):
    result = Counter()
    for index, row in patterns.iterrows():
        findName = row['name']
        findRex = row['rex']
        found = re.findall(findRex, ps)
        if (len(found) > 0):
            result.update({findName:len(found)})
    return result

df['found'] = df['words'].apply(lambda x: countFound(x))
```

[Found DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4Ke9.png)

[Desired Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2D0Wj.png)

| words | stuff | found | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | acb | `{'A': 1, 'B': 1, 'C': 1}` | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| BCD | bcd | `{'B': 1, 'C': 1, 'D': 1}` | 0 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| CDE | cde | `{'C': 1, 'D': 1, 'E': 1}` | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| F | f | `{'F': 1}` | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

```
df.join(pd.json_normalize(df['found']).fillna(0, downcast='infer'))
```

Output:

```
  words stuff                     found  A  B  C  D  E  F
0   ABC   abc  {'A': 1, 'B': 1, 'C': 1}  1  1  1  0  0  0
1  BCDB  bcda  {'B': 2, 'C': 1, 'D': 1}  0  2  1  1  0  0
2   CDE   cde  {'C': 1, 'D': 1, 'E': 1}  0  0  1  1  1  0
3     F     f                  {'F': 1}  0  0  0  0  0  1
```

You can also directly get the columns without your custom function. For this use a dynamically crafted regex with named capturing groups and [`str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html):

```
regex = ('(?P<'+patterns['name']+'>'+patterns['rex']+')').str.cat(sep='|')
# (?P<A>A{1})|(?P<B>B{1})|(?P<C>C{1})|(?P<D>D{1})|(?P<E>E{1})|(?P<F>F{1})

df2 = df.join(df
 ['words']
 .str.extractall(regex)
 .groupby(level=0).count()
 )
```

Or variant without named capturing groups and settings up the column names later:

```
regex = ('('+patterns['rex']+')').str.cat(sep='|')
# (A{1})|(B{1})|(C{1})|(D{1})|(E{1})|(F{1})

print(df.join(df
 ['words']
 .str.extractall(regex)
 .set_axis(patterns['name'], axis=1)
 .groupby(level=0).count()
 ))
```

Output:

```
  words stuff  A  B  C  D  E  F
0   ABC   abc  1  1  1  0  0  0
1  BCDB  bcda  0  2  1  1  0  0
2   CDE   cde  0  0  1  1  1  0
3     F     f  0  0  0  0  0  1
```

Comment: Thank you, both your answer and @code-different 's did the trick!

Answer (score 2):

A `Counter` behaves a lot like a dictionary. Calling `pd.DataFrame` on a list of dictionaries will give you the matrix of counted values:

```py
found = df['words'].apply(countFound).to_list()
pd.concat([
    df.assign(found=found),
    pd.DataFrame(found).fillna(0).astype("int")
], axis=1)
```

Comment: @sammywemmy I think you meant `fillna(0, downcast='infer')` or `fillna(0, downcast='int')` ;)

Comment: Thank you both your answer and @mozway's did the trick.